# Profile time series in pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, pandas

I discovered pandas a short while ago, and it seems very interesting.  Until now I'm usually using structured masked arrays in Python, and it seems pandas can offer an alternative, in particular since I'm often working with time series.  However, at each instant in time, I have some scalar and some array data: scalar time, scalar latitude, scalar longitude, along with vector pressure and vector profile:

`dtype([('lat', '<f4'), ('ch4_profile', '<f4', (110,)), ('time', '<M8[us]'), ('lon', '<f4'), ('p', '<f4', (110,))])`

I would use the data for analysis, such as finding matches with other datasets, and visualisation, such as visualising profiles individually, or some statistic of each profile on a map.

If I understand correctly, pandas' *DataFrame* is 2-dimensional, whereas its *Panel* is 3-dimensional.  Is there any pandas analogue to describe the data as indicated?  Or might I do better to stick with the (more flexible?) standard `ndarray` (for now)?

---

**Edit: Example data**

As per comment, here is some example data, suitable for copy-paste into code (note that in the real world case, I was using a `numpy.ma.MaskedArray`).

```
array([ (70.00604248046875, [1.8543829917907715, 1.8604300022125244, 1.8616620302200317, 1.8601950407028198, 1.851915955543518, 1.8489810228347778, 1.8222110271453857, 1.8655049800872803, 1.7066600322723389, 1.687608003616333, 1.2694480419158936, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 23, 2, 24, 54, 210000), -52.05939865112305, [863.52294921875, 669.9515380859375, 583.3341064453125, 507.91802978515625, 442.25689697265625, 385.1185607910156, 335.3567199707031, 292.0868225097656, 246.5142822265625, 183.48988342285156, 72.71968078613281, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0]),
       (83.92768859863281, [1.8359440565109253, 1.8322449922561646, 1.834841012954712, 1.824031949043274, 1.8172659873962402, 1.8016170263290405, 1.8238199949264526, 1.6459150314331055, 1.6390000581741333, 1.2601679563522339, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 30, 21, 3, 12, 478000), -66.69522094726562, [850.73779296875, 612.4067993164062, 513.5870361328125, 447.0830993652344, 389.2227478027344, 338.8443298339844, 295.01129150390625, 248.8583984375, 190.45912170410156, 78.76023864746094, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0])], 
      dtype=[('lat', '<f4'), ('ch4_profile', '<f4', (110,)), ('time', '<M8[us]'), ('lon', '<f4'), ('p', '<f4', (110,))])
```

Comment: It seems like `Panel` will work or a `MultiIndex` on a `DataFrame`. For a more concrete example, post some data.

Comment: @PaulH I added an example containing two entries.

Comment: oh god. any chance this came from a csv or text file?

Comment: @PaulH It came from an HDF5 file.

Comment: pandas can read HDF5 files directly. see my response working with your array

Comment: @PaulH Right.  I was just playing with pandas and already had my structured `ndarray`.

Answer (score 1):

I flattened your data and threw it into a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas

x = np.array([ 
    (70.00604248046875, [1.8543829917907715, 1.8604300022125244, 1.8616620302200317, 1.8601950407028198, 1.851915955543518, 1.8489810228347778, 1.8222110271453857, 1.8655049800872803, 1.7066600322723389, 1.687608003616333, 1.2694480419158936, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 23, 2, 24, 54, 210000), -52.05939865112305, [863.52294921875, 669.9515380859375, 583.3341064453125, 507.91802978515625, 442.25689697265625, 385.1185607910156, 335.3567199707031, 292.0868225097656, 246.5142822265625, 183.48988342285156, 72.71968078613281, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0]),
    (83.92768859863281, [1.8359440565109253, 1.8322449922561646, 1.834841012954712, 1.824031949043274, 1.8172659873962402, 1.8016170263290405, 1.8238199949264526, 1.6459150314331055, 1.6390000581741333, 1.2601679563522339, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 30, 21, 3, 12, 478000), -66.69522094726562, [850.73779296875, 612.4067993164062, 513.5870361328125, 447.0830993652344, 389.2227478027344, 338.8443298339844, 295.01129150390625, 248.8583984375, 190.45912170410156, 78.76023864746094, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0])
    ], 
    dtype=[('lat', '<f4'), ('ch4', '<f4', (110,)), ('time', '<M8[us]'), ('lon', '<f4'), ('p', '<f4', (110,))]
)

finallist = []
for n, row in enumerate(x):
    for m, (p, ch4) in enumerate(zip(row['p'], row['ch4'])): 
        outputrow = [n, m]
        for ic in ['lat', 'lon', 'time']:
            outputrow.append(row[ic])
        outputrow.extend([p, ch4])
        finallist.append(outputrow)

df = pandas.DataFrame(finallist, columns=['series', 'measurement', 'lat', 'lon', 'time', 'p', 'ch4'])
#df.set_index(['series', 'measurement'], inplace=True)
df['p'][df['p'] < 0] = np.nan
df['ch4'][df['ch4'] < 0] = np.nan

print(df.head().to_string())
```

So then:

```
df.head()

   series  measurement        lat        lon                       time           p       ch4
0       0            0  70.006042 -52.059399 2010-03-23 02:24:54.210000  863.522949  1.854383
1       0            1  70.006042 -52.059399 2010-03-23 02:24:54.210000  669.951538  1.860430
2       0            2  70.006042 -52.059399 2010-03-23 02:24:54.210000  583.334106  1.861662
3       0            3  70.006042 -52.059399 2010-03-23 02:24:54.210000  507.918030  1.860195
4       0            4  70.006042 -52.059399 2010-03-23 02:24:54.210000  442.256897  1.851916
```

And:

```
df.tail()
     series  measurement        lat        lon                       time   p  ch4
215       1          105  83.927689 -66.695221 2010-03-30 21:03:12.478000 NaN  NaN
216       1          106  83.927689 -66.695221 2010-03-30 21:03:12.478000 NaN  NaN
217       1          107  83.927689 -66.695221 2010-03-30 21:03:12.478000 NaN  NaN
218       1          108  83.927689 -66.695221 2010-03-30 21:03:12.478000 NaN  NaN
219       1          109  83.927689 -66.695221 2010-03-30 21:03:12.478000 NaN  NaN
```

so then:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x='ch4', y='p',  use_index=True, subplots=True, ax=ax, legend=True)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$p$')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{CH}_4$')
```

gives:

[image]

Or if you can install seaborn (highly recommended):

```
seaborn.lmplot('ch4', 'p', data=df, hue='series', fit_reg=False)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I see, so the catch here is that the profiles are all along the same axes with the time input repeated.  So to get, for example, the first level for each profile, I would need to index with a step equal to what used to be my pressure-dimension?

Comment: @gerrit i have a different idea, sit tight

Comment: @gerrit check this out